# Microsoft Sans Serif Font not used in Chinese Localized Windows

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7, localization

Scenario:

A UI Interface element appears to use a different font on US English Windows 7 Enterprise compared to "Chinese" Windows 7 Enterprise even with all localization packs and languages set to English.  In the WinForms codebehind, the FontFamily is not explicitly defined and relies on the defaults.

English:

[image: English]

Chinese:

[image: Chinese]

Several questions:

1) What is the font used in the Chinese Windows?
2) What is different about such an install that would cause it to use that font?
3) How do I set up an environment to replicate this?  Is it an install time option on Windows 7 that one does not get when switching UI and System Culture on an already installed Windows 7 instance?

FWIW:

I checked C:\Windows\Fonts and it has the same version and size of "Microsoft Sans Serif Regular"

Comment: Guys, why you think it is not programming related? I am pretty sure that this is standard i18n-programming question.

Comment: Show me where in this post it talks at all about *anything* in the context of programming.  It talks about installing software in different versions of Windows.

Comment: Here are a few resources for anyone dealing with i18n and Localization:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2007/12/17/6784443.aspx  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/ee461121#LocalizationExceptionswithLanguagePacks

Comment: Just FYI, the font shown is [`PMingLiu` (新細明體)](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=36), commonly used in **traditional** Chinese. For simplified Chinese, the font is `SimSun`. Notice that for font sizes small enough, they will use the embedded bitmap glyphs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you haven't done anything to your fonts, default font fall-back mechanism would probably use [SimSun](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=868) as a font replacement for your standard font.

The reason why font is replaced, is that default font on Chinese OS needs to display Chinese characters. And of course due to sheer size, MS Sans Serif does not have Chinese glyphs defined.

To avoid the problem, you might want to "hardcode" font information in resource files – usually simple size modification (i.e. setting 9 instead 8.25) helps. Please be aware, however that if you do that, Chinese characters might appear corrupted – if I recall it correctly it will turn-off font fall-back mechanism completely. It might be appropriate for "static" UI elements that are not going to be translated to Chinese but would be totally unacceptable for text boxes and similar controls which allow users to enter free-form text.

Instead of fighting the rendering issues, it is best to just let it pass. I am sure that Chinese users are simply used to that specific look & feel.

Comment: this issue is resolved by hard coding the 'default english' UI font (Microsoft Sans Serif) into the form/controls.

Comment: @TodK: Yes, it will "resolve" this issue, but hollow boxes might appear if user enter non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Makes sense - the area where I made the changes were non-input.  Thanks!

Comment: @Paweł Dyda: Why is size 9 preferable to size 8.25? Should I replace my Microsoft Sans Serif 8.25 font with Microsoft Sans Serif 9 for better compatibility worldwide generally?

Comment: @DanW: To be honest, I don't recommend modifying the fonts at all. It was meant to be an example of what you can do to prevent changing the font face in your Winforms application across different language versions of Windows.